# How to select rows when there is no value in a related table?

Tags: python, database, django, django-queryset

I have the following schema:

```
class ModelA(models.Model)
    sold = models.DateFiled(blank=True, null=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

I want to get all instances of `ModelA` which do not have related *any* `ModelB` with `end` date set to `Null`, are enabled and not "sold".

Currently I have the following queryset:

```
ModelA.objects.exclude(
    pk__in=ModelB.objects.filter(end__isnull=True).values('model_a_id')
).filter(
    enabled=True, sold__isnull=True
)
```

But it's performance is very poor, is there any better way to model this query/Queryset?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? If something SQL, have you considered constructing a raw SQL query? Perhaps a LEFT JOIN on one of the tables to return the rows as long as the table has said value?

Comment: This has to be pretty much DB agnostic, currently this works with SQLite and PostgreSQL, haven't testes with MySQL. And I saw that django inlines first queryset into a subquery, but still performs poorly.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually filter on the ModelB relation from ModelA, and get Django to perform a left outer join. The following query should do a join instead of using a subquery:

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = ModelA.objects.exclude(Q(model_b__isnull=False) & Q(model_b__end__isnull=True))
```

Try the above in a django shell, and do `print q.query` to see how it translates to SQL. The `Q()` syntax lets you do an "OR" filter. We're basically saying: get me all ModelA that dont: have a modelB relation with end__isnull=True.

I think that logic covers the cases you're looking for. Otherwise, you can do something similar.

Comment: Hm... what errors are you seeing? I'm pretty confident in this as a solution!

Comment: No erros, just wrong results, if I have 2 ModelB instances, pointing to the same ModelA in DB, one with end date, and second without end date, I don't want to include this ModelA into resultset, yours way would include it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I edited my query -- try it now. There is a difference between the logic required for negating a "filter" to make the equivalent "exclude" that I didn't account for.

Comment: That's even worse than my first solution, if you add enabled filtering: `ModelA.objects.exclude(...).filter(enabled=True)` makes that django generates 2 subquerys

Comment: I've added a few more details to question